# Expandable table cell content overflowing from cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have an expandable tableview in my project as part of my tableviewcontroller. The issue is that when the table is not expanded, the rest of the cell is displayed anyway, overlapping with the next cell. The method I used to create expandable tables is from this tutorial: https://dev.to/lawgimenez/implementing-the-expandable-cell-in-ios-uitableview-f7j

I think they changed some things because this code was written in an older version of xcode and swift.

I have tried changing some properties of the cells and the tableview but nothing has worked so far.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

             tableViewData[indexPath.row].opened = !tableViewData[indexPath.row].opened

             tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

            if tableViewData[indexPath.row].opened == true {
                return 99.5
            }
            else {
                return 40.5
            }

    }
```

I expected the cell in the tableview to cut off the custom cell at the exact height of the cell in the tableview but instead the cell is small when not expanded but all of the custom cell is diaplayed and overflows from assigned area for the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

instead of

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Another thing, you should use

```
if tableViewData[indexPath.row].opened {

}
```

instead of

```
if tableViewData[indexPath.row].opened == true {

}
```

Comment: And he can use `tableViewData[indexPath.row].opened.toggle()`
instead of `tableViewData[indexPath.row].opened = !tableViewData[indexPath.row].opened`

Comment: Hi @MiguelAngelOlmedoPerez welcome to stack overflow. It is great if you could explain a bit more why you are making the code suggestions - for example, _pass the additional at: and with: parameters to specify the foo of the bar in the baz, if you leave those out you get gazoink._